# Jenkins CI ConsoleLog format

Tags: jenkins

I have searched the web but can not seems to find any information about the job log file.

The job log file contains all the stdout that the build generates, that is fine and in the webinterface you can get a clean look, but if you look directly at the file you get this:

```
[8mha:AAABRR+LCAAAAAAAAACFj8FKxDAQhsdqtXjUiwjCgqi3tEoVdU9ru/VSvSwKsqe4m60r3aQmqVQEn8eDvoxv4GkR8R1MmmZFPDg55GPy/zN/Xr7AFRy2b8qhYBQVeZmNqUCYivGA5YyjjqJI0zmTBEzNOeCk4NWCM1xI2EmN32/8/szvz/xK2E5hYYgllrCS3uJ77OeYZn5P8jHN2hWH9SbFgFHBcoIic//eDFWhAm/9H1gt/Hz22PtVb+rAfB/c66wOu9r/u1y9jvTrHTzBokpJ8YRodqqi5NaBtAM1jte3y+nHxuNpHUgl8yQsbYaRPpqSJFClKQg0m56l8OBw7yS0uiSxOkNJXaXe79nJQWDnRfHPZM2mZ2m3e9TM050otjpD3X19JLiVJHwiYe1CqL+0hORYkuzhuBWTES5zufwNzjSVeRcCAAA=[0mUsing strategy: Default
```

Which looks kinda like base64 encode, but is not.

And a line which is only 20 chars long suddenly becomes like 200 chars is going to use a lof of space, when you have 80.000 lines.

Why does it look like that and can i use that "hash" to anything?

Comment: What's the path to your file relative to $JENKINS_HOME on the master, and what version of Jenkins are you using ?  In my installation the log files are readable.

Comment: I am using Jenkins ver. 1.488 (at work), and the path is ./jobs/MYNAME/builds/17/log. It has then properly been fixed in a newer version, hmm.